# Multiply defined symbols found?

Tags: c++, static

I made my own library and compiled it as a static library in MSVC using the MD multithreaded DLL runtime. I then compiled my application and included myLib.lib and when I do I get tons of multiply defined symbols relating to MSVCRTLIB, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application and all libraries must be compiled with the same settings. Make sure they all use the MD option.